# How do I setup a tunnel piercing scenario on my Ubuntu client to access the internet through my own server including port knocking on it?

Tags: networking, server, internet, client

Google isn't my friend with this long term issue which is up to date for my upcoming holidays again.

It would be **great** if you could provide a road warrior setup for DNS as well as IP tunneling as a backup solution.

Keywords are: iodine (DNS) httptunnel (IP) 
and *maybe* these programs for the port knocking(?):

```
fwknop-apparmor-profile, fwknop-client/server, knockdd (IP and DNS)
```

I would also really appreciate any hints to howtos or other tutorials or best practices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IP Tunneling could be achieved by a PPTP VPN. DNS by BIND and if you want to use Iodine, by using a second VPS. Port knocking is then used to secure the setup. All of these topics are well documented:
Port knocking:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-port-knocking-using-only-iptables-on-an-ubuntu-vps
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-port-knocking-to-hide-your-ssh-daemon-from-attackers-on-ubuntu
I'd recommend only setting up the daemon on a port knock for additional security.

PPTP VPN:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/vpn?type=tutorials
https://github.com/viljoviitanen/setup-simple-pptp-vpn

Iodine:
http://benjaminkerensa.com/2012/05/25/tunneling-ipv4-traffic-over-dns-on-ubuntu-12-04
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/iodine.8.html
http://dev.kryo.se/iodine/wiki/HowtoSetup
http://clevarme.blogspot.com/2011/07/dns-tunneling.html